# What's the most elegant way to refactor this when the only difference is the key name of a return object?

Tags: typescript, refactoring

What's the most elegant way to refactor this when the only difference is the key name of a return object ?

```
function generateContactInput(rawData, contactId) {
  const data = rawData
    ? rawData.replace(/["]+/g, '').split(SEMICOLON)
    : undefined;
  const populatedData = data
    ? data.map((value) => ({ contactId, value }))
    : undefined;
  if (Array.isArray(populatedData) && populatedData.length > 0)
    populatedData[0].isPrimary = true;
  return populatedData;
}

function generateContactAddressInput(rawAddresses, contactId) {
  const data = rawAddresses
    ? rawAddresses.replace(/["]+/g, '').split(SEMICOLON)
    : undefined;
  const populatedData = data
    ? data.map((streetAddress) => ({ contactId, streetAddress }))
    : undefined;
  if (Array.isArray(populatedData) && populatedData.length > 0)
    populatedData[0].isPrimary = true;
  return populatedData;
}
```

The only difference is that line :

`? data.map((streetAddress) => ({ contactId, streetAddress }))`

Comment: Btw, I think this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the better place for refactoring

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is creating a single helper function that receives a name to be used in mapping:

```
function generateInput(rawData, contactId, fieldName) {
  const data = rawData
    ? rawData.replace(/["]+/g, '').split(SEMICOLON)
    : undefined;
  const populatedData = data
    ? data.map((value) => ({ contactId, [fieldName]: value }))
    : undefined;
  if (Array.isArray(populatedData) && populatedData.length > 0)
    populatedData[0].isPrimary = true;
  return populatedData;
}
```

... then either use this helper function directly, or create a series of its wrappers with predefined values:

```
function generateContactInput(rawData, contactId) {
  return generateInput(rawData, contactId, 'value');
}

function generateContactAddressInput(rawData, contactId) {
  return generateInput(rawData, contactId, 'streetAddress');
}
```

---

As a matter of fact, I would consider rewriting the code to drop the ternaries, too:

```
function generateInput(rawData, contactId, fieldName) {
  if (!rawData) return; // no need to drag this special case through the whole code

  const data = rawData.replace(/["]+/g, '').split(SEMICOLON);
  const populatedData = data.map((value) => ({ contactId, [fieldName]: value }));
  if (populatedData.length > 0) 
    populatedData[0].isPrimary = true;
  return populatedData;
}
```

Comment: Also for refactor, we can use `?.` syntax. `const data = rawData?.replace(...` and `const populatedData = data?.map(....`

Comment: Good point. This might require adjusting the building pipeline (if `?.` for some reasons is not supported yet), but this will make the code more readable.

Comment: In fact, I think the code will look better if it just handles this special case once. In the original code, both `data` and `populatedData` might be equal to `undefined` only if `rawData` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if you are interested in functional approach

```js
const compose = (...fns: any[]) => (data: any) => fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), data);

const SEMICOLON = ';'

const rawInfo = (contactId, name) => (value) => ({ contactId, [name]: value })

const replace = (rawData) => rawData ? rawData.replace(/["]+/g, '').split(SEMICOLON) : undefined

const populate = (cb) => (data) => data ? data.map(cb) : undefined

const array = (data) => {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        const [head, ...tail] = data

        const newHead = {
            ...head,
            isPrimary: true
        }
        return [newHead, ...tail]
    }

    return data
}

const handler = (rawData, contactId, strategy: 'value' | 'streetAddress') =>
    compose(array, populate(rawInfo(contactId, strategy)), replace)(rawData)
```

[Here](https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose) you can find my article about typing `compose` function

Comment: `rawData ? rawData.replace(/["]+/g, '').split(SEMICOLON) : undefined` can be `rawData ?? rawData.replace(/["]+/g, '').split(SEMICOLON)`. Same with the `populate` function. Also, the whole "if there is data, use it, otherwise do nothing" is abstracted at a higher level with the `Option`/`Optional`/`Maybe` functor (different common names for the same thing).

Comment: Also, I'm personally not a big fan of the `compose` defined like that. I recognise that it correctly encodes `f(g(x))` as `compose(f, g)(x)` but I prefer the opposite direction (sometimes called "pipe") where if you read `pipe(f, g)(x)` you know that first `f` is applied, then `g`.

Comment: @VLAZ you are right, there are a lot of things could be improved in my answer. Honestly, did not have enough time even to provide all types . You know - types are important for me :) Looking forward for your answer with `pipe`.

Comment: @VLAZ could you please recommend some articles/books/blog about functional programming?

Comment: I like the [Mostly Adequate Guide to Functional Programming](https://mostly-adequate.gitbook.io/mostly-adequate-guide/). [Composing Software: The Book](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/composing-software-the-book-f31c77fc3ddc) is a series of Medium articles. I've not actually read it but I've read other articles by the same author and I'd trust him. There is also [this guide for scriptum](https://github.com/kongware/scriptum/blob/master/course/ch-001.md) which is written with JS in mind. The [author is on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5536315/iven-marquardt).

Comment: Also, might be of interest - fp-ts is a TS library that provides functional constructs like [Option](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html). There is also Purify (literally just found it while googling for the fp-ts docs) which does the same thing. It has [Maybe](https://gigobyte.github.io/purify/adts/Maybe/) as an example.